# UI Freezing on ASINetworkQueue request

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTpREQUEST

I am adding about 10 requests to  ASINetworkQueue and calling go
( exactly like in the sample code ) .

But as soon as my queue starts my iphone ui totally freezes and
"unfreezes" only when queue is done .

I want my UIAction to take priority over network activity .
 Should i be doing/ setting something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you are using asynchronous requests, not synchronous?  It sounds like synchronous (which will block the UI thread) in the situation you're describing.